# How does HTML5 support m3u8 playlist?

Tags: html, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm finding a way to play the m3u8 playlist with pure HTML5/JavaScript. HTML5 should not rely on flash to support HTTP Live Stream.

Are there any HTML5 player that support m3u8 without flash and other fallbacks?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, Safari on iOS does support HLS in the video element.

Comment: Yes, it is. However the Safari on iOS requires the native decoders which not HTML5 things.